# Interpretation of $\vec{x}$ in QFT

Tags: quantum-mechanics, field-theory, discrete, lattice-model

I am **still** at an early stage of studying Quantum Field Theory (I am reading *QFT In A Nutshell by A. Zee*).

In the book I'm reading, it starts from a discrete lattice of material "lumps" labeled by $a$, seperated from each other by a finite $l$, so that the position of lump $a$ is $q_a(t)$. The next step is to take $l \to 0$ and "promote":

> $$
> q \to \varphi
> $$
>   $$
> a \to \vec{x}
> $$ 
>   $$
> q_a(t) \to \varphi (t, \vec{x}) = \varphi (x)
> $$
>   $$
> \sum_a \to \int d^Dx
> $$

If this was in the realm of (classical) continuum mechanics, $\vec{x}$ would simply label the simplified and theoretical (This aspect of physics benefits from this simplification at no cost) infinitesimal lump that was *actually* displaced by $\vec{x}$ from the origin at $t=0$.

In QFT though, by definition, the field is not meant to be a simplification of anything. It's meant to be quite the contrary. I am not yet confident enough to ask my concrete questions, because I realize that they carry with them implicit assumptions which are probably false. So I'll just ask:

If it's not the displacement $\vec{x}$, and It's not the  classical label $\vec{x}$, then, what is it? What does it mean?

Comment: The book is Zee, QFT in a nutshell?

Comment: @innisfree Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Initially the label $a$ represent the site on a lattice with sites separated by distance $l$. i.e., the discrete position for each of a collection of oscillators, $q_a$, with an oscillator at each lattice site.

When we take the continuum limit, $l\to0$, the label $a$ becomes continuous, i.e. it becomes the position variable $x$. We now have an infinite collection of oscillators, labelled by their position $x$ - an oscillator at each point in space.

The oscillators don't themselves move about, they're fixed at the lattice sites (and later points in space). But they are correlated. An oscillation in $q_1$ might be correlated with an oscillation in its next door neighbour, $q_2$. The propagation of oscillations in that way is basically particles propagating.

Comment: It could have been an infinite collection in the discrete case as well, and replaced by uncountable in the continuum limit. But It's not essential :).

Comment: @Dror, yes that's true. I hope I managed to answer your question, I couldn't really understand your confusion. QFT is a tough subject for self-study. If possible, I advise banding together with someone else and discussing the book. If that's not possible, keep going all the same!

Comment: So, for example, if 2 particular oscillators ($1$ at $x_1$ and $2$ at $x_2$) switch their position at a later time, then $x_1$/$x_2$ becomes the label of $2$/$1$?

Comment: I don't think that's the right picture. The oscillators don't themselves move about, they're fixed at the lattice sites (and later points in space). But they are correlated. An oscillation in $q_1$ might be correlated with an oscillation in its next door neighbour, $q_2$. The propagation of oscillations in that way is basically particles propagating.

Comment: Given *this* question, how do you estimate my odds at grasping the entire book (By my self) "properly" enough? :)

Comment: I asked tonnes of questions throughout my physics education (and wanted to ask tonnes more dumb ones but didn't and thought silly things for longer than necessary!). 

Have you studied maths, special relativity and quantum mechanics to a reasonable level? If so, aim to fully grasp the first 150 pages or so, and get the gist of the rest.

Comment: My maths and SR is better than reasonable. QM is at reasonable. I'll talk to you in a 100 pages :). (BTW I honestly don't think this question is silly/dumb :).